# If group homomorphisms preserve inverses, why aren't they just isomorphisms?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

If group homomorphisms preserve inverses, why aren't they just isomorphisms? Because if the homomorphism $\phi$ preserves inverses, then isn't $\phi$ bijective hence an isomorphism?

Comment: Try it out with a homomorphism that is not an isomorphism! You will see that it maps an inverse of an element to the inverse of the image. The homomorphism itself need not have an inverse mapping.

Comment: For a counterexample, the map $f:G\to G$ mapping everything in $G$ to the identity is a homomorphism.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the phrase "preserves inverses". If $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism, then $b=a^{-1}$ for some $b\in G$ means $f(b)=[f(a)]^{-1}$ in $H$. But @probably_someone's example shows why this isn't enough to be able to 'go backwards' as in an isomorphism.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you for taking the time to help me. When I first initially saw this in class, I was very confused. I searched some things online and still didn't feel confident. Thanks again!

Comment: Why was this put on hold? It makes perfectly clear sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: for $\phi$ to be bijective it needs to *have* an inverse as a map, which is totally different from *preserving* inverses in the group structure.  To have an inverse would mean there is a map $\phi^{-1}$ such that the compositions $\phi\circ\phi^{-1}$ and $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi$ are the identity maps.  To preserve inverses means that for any $g$ in the domain of $\phi$, $\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(g)^{-1}$.

For a simple concrete example, consider the homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi(n)=0$ for all $n$.  This map preserves inverses, meaning that $\phi(-n)=-\phi(n)$ for all $n$ (both sides are equal to $0$).  But it certainly is not a bijection!

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It is about the isomorphism itself having an inverse and not the elements itself. For homomorphisms, its the elements with inverses that are preserved...